# NativeScript: SQLCipher isn't accepting a PBKDF2 derived key as a valid string

Tags: sqlite, nativescript, sqlcipher

I'm using SQLCipher on my NativeScript project and my I'm pretty sure I'm passing an encryption key in the correct format but I always get this message:

`JS: Invalid key type, key must be a string.\nDatabase will not be encrypted.`

This is how I'm deriiving the key:

`CryptoJS.PBKDF2("password", "salt", { keySize: 512/64, iterations: 1000 }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);`

The funny thing is, if I pass a random key using WordArray it'll accept it without any problem.

`CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(32).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `sha256("").toString()` instead of PBKDF2.